# Implementing Active/Passive Topology in Java

Tags: java, fault-tolerance, single-instance

Need to implement active/passive topology for a Java instance.

The requirement is if active becomes unavailable due to some reason then passive takes over active and active becomes passive. 
It's just a java application which just putting data into DB after doing some processing on it.

Two Questions: 
1. How to handle active/passive instances.Is there any third party API that can be applied? 
2. What should be the proper handling of the instance which went down i.e. the active one?

Comment: Is this java application has some http endpoint or at least available via TCP?

Comment: Nope. it's standalone java application.

Comment: How do you plan to check for application instance availability?

Comment: 1. If there is a GC long pause that means application struggling with memory so better to drop it. GC optimization is different aspect that can be looked at but to recover from that point I think its better flip the instances.

Comment: If there are OOM exceptions, any other errors which has actually stopped the application to respond then better to flip the instances.

Comment: IMO, you are better off using a separate orchestration solution (swarm, kubermetes, open-shift, fabric-8, aws, etc, etc) then trying to bake this into the app....

Comment: how did you finally build this solution ?